# Merging nodes with identical element with XQuery

Tags: xquery

I wonder whether someone could point my very rusty xquery in the right direction.

I have a simple xml file:

```
<factoids>
  <set>
    <head>smith, joe</head>
    <factoid> <!-- contains set of elements --> </factoid>
    <factoid> <!-- contains set of elements --> </factoid>
  </set>
  <set>
    <head>miller, jim</head>
    <factoid> <!-- contains set of elements --> </factoid>
    <factoid> <!-- contains set of elements --> </factoid>
  </set>
  <set>
    <head>smith, joe</head>
    <factoid> <!-- contains set of elements --> </factoid>
    <factoid> <!-- contains set of elements --> </factoid>
  </set>
  ...
</factoids>
```

I would simply like to merge all factoid-sets featuring the identical content in the head-element.

I am sure I have done this in the distant past with some simple xquery.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Please edit your question with a few sample elements and the expected output.

Comment: I merely need to have all the <factoid>s belonging to one person (currently distributed, but with the same content of <head>) grouped together...

Comment: I sort of understand, but still - see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is a text book grouping question:

```
<factoids>
{
    for $set in factoids/set
    group by $head := $set/head
    return
        <set>
            <head>{$head}</head>
            { $set/factoid }
        </set>
}
</factoids>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVSgeV

Comment: It is. Thanks very much!

Comment: I was using something very similar. I assumed that a different approach was needed, since it wasn't working. See below the working solution with minor xpath tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Thanks, again, to all the hints!

```
xquery version "3.0";
<factoids>
{
    for $fact in //factoid
    group by $pers := $fact/../head
    order by $pers
    return
         <set>
            <head>{$pers}</head>
            { $fact }
        </set>
}
</factoids>
```